# What is the correct config settings to automate test in parallel using Protractor?

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor

Here is my settings. Is there a correct setting for angular/non-angular application test in parallel? Sometimes, either my firefox or chrome hangs while the other one is running. Is it the **ignoreSynchronization** suppose to be set to **true** and **waitForAngular** to be **false**? I feel like there is too much time syncing problem that is causing one of the browsers to hang?

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 600000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    framework: 'custom',
    // path relative to the current config file
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    multiCapabilities:
    [{
      'browserName': 'firefox',
      specs: 'features/firefox/*.feature',
    },
    {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      specs: 'features/chrome/*.feature',
    }],
    maxSessions: 2,
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:8080',
    cucumberOpts: {
      strict: true,
      require: [
        'hooks/hooks.js',
        'specs/*Spec.js'
      ],
      tags: [
        "@runThis", 
        "~@ignoreThis"
      ],
      profile: false,
      format: 'json:./e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json',
      resultJsonOutputFile: './e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'
    },
    beforeLaunch: function() {
      const fs = require('fs');
      const path = require('path');

      const directory = './e2e/reports';

      //cleans up the json results from the previous build when using node flake
      fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (const file of files) {
          fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        }
      });
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
      var chai = require('chai');
      chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
      global.expect = chai.expect;
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.manage().window().maximize();
      browser.waitForAngular(false);           
      browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000); 

    },
    ghostMode:false
}
```

Comment: just adding these 2 lines inside the capabilities should be enough: `shardTestFiles: true` and `maxInstances: 2`

Answer (score 0):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated so you do not need to set that. However you do need to set `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` instead of `browser.waitForAngular(false)` like you have in your conf. waitForAngular is what is called before every action when waitForAngularEnabled is true.

Setup your onPrepare like

```
onPrepare: function() {
  var chai = require('chai');
  chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
  global.expect = chai.expect;
  browser.manage().window().maximize();
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);           
  browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000); 
},
```

Your specific situation will depend on what you are trying to achieve from your parallel execution.

This setup will divide your tests across 2 browser types, chrome and firefox, and execute your tests in parallel. It will support 3 chrome and 2 firefox browsers running at any one time. Tests are divided based on whichever finishing first

```
multiCapabilities: [
    { browserName: "chrome", shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 3 },
    { browserName: "firefox", shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 2 },
],
maxSessions: 10, //controls the total number of instances, won't be relevant in this case
```

This setup will execute all your tests on BOTH a chrome and firefox browser. If you are running 5 specs you will have 10 results.

```
multiCapabilities: [
    { browserName: "firefox" },
    { browserName: "chrome" },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Above given answers with adding shardTestFiles: true, and number of maxInstances should work. However I would still want to highlight that if you are using webdriver-manager start to start selenium server (which I think you are based on the selenium address given in config file) then do not expect that it will  work as smooth as selenium grid solution to run tests in parallel on different browsers.
Webdriver-manager is designed as a quickest solution to start selenium server and is not a replacement of selenium-grid.